# Load window icon dynamically

Tags: c++, winapi, icons

When registering a window class `WNDCLASSEX wcex`, I use `wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, (LPCTSTR) IDI_APPLICATION )` to set the icon of the window.

Is there a way to dynamically load the icon from a file for registering the window?
Something like `LoadIcon ( hInstance, "iconfile.ico" )` or may be create the Icon Resource using the file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
wcex.hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage( // returns a HANDLE so we have to cast to HICON
  NULL,             // hInstance must be NULL when loading from a file
  "iconfile.ico",   // the icon file name
  IMAGE_ICON,       // specifies that the file is an icon
  0,                // width of the image (we'll specify default later on)
  0,                // height of the image
  LR_LOADFROMFILE|  // we want to load a file (as opposed to a resource)
  LR_DEFAULTSIZE|   // default metrics based on the type (IMAGE_ICON, 32x32)
  LR_SHARED         // let the system release the handle when it's no longer used
);
```

Make sure to either set `wcex.hIconSm` (small icon) to NULL or load a small icon. When you set it to NULL, it will use the image specified by hIcon automatically. When you load a small icon with LoadImage, you should set the width and height to 16 and remove the LR_DEFAULTSIZE flag. If it's an icon designed to have transparent parts, add the LR_LOADTRANSPARENT flag

Comment: From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx): Do not use LR_SHARED for images that have non-standard sizes, that may change after loading, or that are loaded from a file.