# Is there a way to change icon of a Window class from an external process?

Tags: winapi

I'd like to change application icon dynamically at runtime from an external process. I found out [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187453/load-window-icon-dynamically) that to change the icon of a window class from inside of the running process is to first load the icon using [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
HICON IconHandle = (HICON) LoadImage( // returns a HANDLE so we have to cast to HICON
  NULL,             // hInstance must be NULL when loading from a file
  "iconfile.ico",   // the icon file name
  IMAGE_ICON,       // specifies that the file is an icon
  0,                // width of the image (we'll specify default later on)
  0,                // height of the image
  LR_LOADFROMFILE|  // we want to load a file (as opposed to a resource)
  LR_DEFAULTSIZE|   // default metrics based on the type (IMAGE_ICON, 32x32)
  LR_SHARED         // let the system release the handle when it's no longer used
);
```

And then I can set this icon for the window class using [SetClassLongPtrA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptra):

```
SetClassLongPtrA(MyWindowHandle, GCLP_HICON, (ULONG_PTR)IconHandle);
```

I'd like to change icons of applications externally from my own application. The only way I can see I can do it right now is by injecting a dll into the target process, get windows of the process and then change the icons for classes of these windows. It works, but I'd prefer to be able to do this externally without injection. I feel like there is no way, but I thought I'd ask, maybe someone knows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to do this externally without injection.

If you want to change icon of a Window class from an external process, you need to load the dll into the target process. And then use the functions `CreateIconFromResourceEx`, `DrawIcon`, and `LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx`, and several of the resource functions, to create an icon handle based on icon data from another executable file. Then, it displays the icon in a window.

Refer to the Doc:[Sharing Icon Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-icons#sharing-icon-resources)

Comment: Completely misses to main issue: Window classes are registered *per process*. If you wish to change a window class, you absolutely must do it from within that process.